detrmine height of table when converting html to pdf with iText7.pdfhtml
I'm working with iText7.pdfhtml and need to find the height of a table when (or before) converting the html code to pdf.
The height of the table will be used to set the height of another div element (class "map") in the html, that is positioned before the table in the html.
The html looks like this:
    <div pagenumber="1" class="page portrait bordered">
      <div class="map bordered" style="height: 780px;">
 
      </div>
      <table id="Werkplekken" class="colofon">
        <tbody>
          <tr class="colofon">
            <td class="colofon emptycell wpk_a" />
            <td class="colofon werkplekletter">A</td>
            <td class="colofon">grind vervangen</td>
            <td class="colofon">02-05-2024 01:00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="colofon">
            <td class="colofon emptycell wpk_b" />
            <td class="colofon werkplekletter">B</td>
            <td class="colofon">dwarsliggers vervangen</td>
            <td class="colofon">02-05-2024 03:00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="colofon">
            <td class="colofon emptycell wpk_c" />
            <td class="colofon werkplekletter">C</td>
            <td class="colofon">wissels onderhoud</td>
            <td class="colofon">03-05-2024 00:00</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>


The table dat element can contain wrapped text, so it's not just a matter of counting rows and multply by font-height.
I tried a Custom TableTagWorker, but cannot figure it out.
    public int GetColofonHeight(int paginaNummer, string colofonId)
    {
        int height = 0;
        XElement colofon = GetColofon(paginaNummer, colofonId);
        if (colofon != null)
        {
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(stream);
            writer.SetCloseStream(false);
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
            ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
            properties.SetBaseUri(RESOURCESURI);
            properties.SetTagWorkerFactory(new TableTagWorkerFactory((v) => { height = v; }));
            HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(colofon.ToString(), pdf, properties);
            pdf.Close();
        }
        return height;
    }

    internal class TableTagWorkerFactory : DefaultTagWorkerFactory
    {
    private Action<int> SetHeight;

    public TableTagWorkerFactory(Action<int> SetHeight)
    {
        this.SetHeight = SetHeight;
    }

    public override ITagWorker GetCustomTagWorker(IElementNode tag, ProcessorContext context)
    {
        if ("table".Equals(tag.Name(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return new CustomTableTagWorker(tag, context, this.SetHeight);
        }

        return null;
    }
}

    internal class CustomTableTagWorker : TableTagWorker
    {
    private PdfDocument pdfDocument;
    private Action<int> SetHeight;

    public CustomTableTagWorker(IElementNode tag, ProcessorContext context, Action<int> SetHeight) : base(tag, context)
    {
        if(tag.GetAttribute("class") == "colofon")
        {
            this.pdfDocument = context.GetPdfDocument();
            this.SetHeight = SetHeight;
        }
    }

    public override bool ProcessContent(string content, ProcessorContext context)
    {
        return base.ProcessContent(content, context);
    }

    public override void ProcessEnd(IElementNode element, ProcessorContext context)
    {
        base.ProcessEnd(element, context);
    }

    public override string GetDisplay()
    {
        return base.GetDisplay();
    }

    public override IPropertyContainer GetElementResult()
    {
        int h = 0;
        IPropertyContainer result = base.GetElementResult();
        if(pdfDocument != null)
        {
            Table table = (Table)result;
            if (table.GetHeight().IsPointValue()) { SetHeight((int)table.GetHeight().GetValue() ); } else { SetHeight(0); }

            
        }
        return result;
      }
    }

rendering the html in browser control is not an option since the code is inside a class library (.NET 7.0).
Does anyone have suggestions for me?
